# C++ constexpr compilation issue

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constexpr

I am unable to compile this test case for a basic vector graphic point class.  Please help me figure out what is missing.  Thanks!

**Compile error:** Constexpr variable 'i' must be initialized by a constant expression

**Test case:**

```
TEST(constexprPoint, Point)
{
    constexpr int i = VG::Point{4, 5}.getX(); // <-- compile error

    CHECK_EQUAL(i, 4);
}
```

**Header file:**

```
namespace VG {
    class Point{
    public:
        Point(const int x, const int y) : myX{x},myY{y} {}
        constexpr int getX() const;
        constexpr int getY() const;
    private:
        const int myX, myY;
    };
}
```

**Source file:**

```
namespace VG {

    constexpr int Point::getX() const {
        return myX;
    }

    constexpr int Point::getY() const {
        return myY;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your object is not defined. You can make the function static or define the fucnction outside of a class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your constructor `constexpr` as well.

Please see [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) for more information about how `constexpr` (including constructors) behave.

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate errors.

1. You need to make your constructor `constexpr`
2. You need to move your functions to the header file (body of a constexpr function must be visible at the point of use).

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/3am8D5)